# View PDF file converted to BLOB image in UIImage or UIScroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

my App requirement is to view uploaded documents from IPAD. 
i am importing document from database in the form of BLOB image and passing it to IPAD and with below code i could view image.

```
NSString *strImage; // String has BLOB image from DB

NSData *imageData = [self dataFromBase64EncodedString:strImage];

UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

UIImageView *m_oImageViewer = [[UIImageView alloc]init];

m_oImageViewer.image = image;
m_oImageViewer.frame=CGRectMake((self.view.frame.size.width/2)- 250,60,500,500);
[self.view addSubview:m_oImageViewer];


-(NSData *)dataFromBase64EncodedString:(NSString *)string{
if (string.length > 0) 
{
     NSString *data64URLString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:;base64,%@", string];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:data64URLString]];
    return data;
}
return nil;
```

If PDF file converted to BLOB why i am getting image as nil, as i can see BLOB is common so why only .png files i can se and not PDF file even after converting to BLOB.
i read support document for UIImage it does not give PDF file but i am giving BLOB image. where i am going wrong. 
i have to use any other property, or this is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

PDF isn't image format, its something like container with text, fonts, vector and raster images etc, so you can't convert it into UIImage, but UIWebView can show pdf (and a lot another format). I think, you should save pdf BLOB to temp folder and then show it in UIWebView, something like:

```
    [pdfData writeToFile:tempFilePath atomically:YES];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:tempFilePath];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [self.webView  loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Ok but my PDF files i m converting to BLOB image inside Stored Procedure that does not mean it will give one particular formate which i can decode in iPAD. as .png is also BLOB and PDF file also BLOB.

Comment: I suppose that convertion from NSData to UIImage means that png-file (or jpeg) was only loaded to NSData without any other encoding, so pdf-file was loaded the same way and it can be readed as pdf if you save it to disk

Comment: ok why i was doing because here only on stackoverflow i read it should be possible as ultimately it is an BLOB file. but nothing else was mentioned. if at all this is not possible than can you please tel me UIWebView example. till now i am trying to get any example of such control. or any control which i can use for my TASk.

Comment: ok why i was doing because here only on stackoverflow i read it should be possible as ultimately it is an BLOB file. but nothing else was mentioned. if at all this is not possible than can you please tel me UIWebView example. till now i am trying to get any example of such control. or any control which i can use for my TASk. self.webView i have to declare and initialise like other controller ....only or any specific platform i need to add...and my BLOB image i am saving in NEMutableArray as string. do i have to save other place.

Comment: sorry for long answer time, I had a lot job. How to load some type of file into UIWebView you can see [here][1]. About saving to other place - I think yuo should do so cause I  don't know any way to load it without saving. You can use NSTemporaryDirectory for it


  [1]: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1630/_index.html